# Hadoop DistributedCache is deprecated - what is the preferred API?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My map tasks need some configuration data, which I would like to distribute via the Distributed Cache.

The Hadoop [MapReduce Tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache) shows the [usage](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v2.0) of the DistributedCache class, roughly as follows:

```
// In the driver
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), WordCount.class);
...
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri(), conf); 

// In the mapper
Path[] myCacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
...
```

However, `DistributedCache` is [marked as deprecated](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) in Hadoop 2.2.0.

What is the new preferred way to achieve this? Is there an up-to-date example or tutorial covering this API?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The APIs for the Distributed Cache can be found in the Job class itself. Check the documentation here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html
 The code should be something like

```
Job job = new Job();
...
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());
```

In your mapper code:

```
Path[] localPaths = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
...
```

Comment: Thanks - and I assume that I therefore need to use the newer `mapreduce` API rather than `mapred`, otherwise the `JobContext` object is not provided to the mapper...

Comment: I think `getLocalCacheFiles()` is deprecated, but `getCacheFiles()` is OK - returns URIs not Paths though.

Comment: Nice! This is a much cleaner and simpler API than using DistributedCache.

Comment: @DNA I don't think `getLocalCacheFiles()` and `getCacheFiles()` are the same. You can check my question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492964/are-getcachefiles-and-getlocalcachefiles-the-same). If you want to access localized files but don't want to use the deprecated api, you can use the file name to directly open it(the behind technique is called symbolic link).

Comment: but what if we use some framework (like cascading) that creates the jobs? We can only pass the jobconf to cascading framework - whats the alternative to DistributedCache in this case?

Comment: context.getLocalCacheFiles(); is deprecated using Hadoop 2.6.4

Comment: I am using `JobConf` in my driver. How do I move to `Job`, as in, what changes would I have to make?

Answer (score 25):

To expand on @jtravaglini, the preferred way of using `DistributedCache` for YARN/MapReduce 2 is as follows:

In your driver, use the `Job.addCacheFile()`

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "MyJob");

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);

    // ...

    // Mind the # sign after the absolute file location.
    // You will be using the name after the # sign as your
    // file name in your Mapper/Reducer
    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/yourname/cache/some_file.json#some"));
    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/yourname/cache/other_file.json#other"));

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

And in your Mapper/Reducer, override the `setup(Context context)` method:

```
@Override
protected void setup(
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (context.getCacheFiles() != null
            && context.getCacheFiles().length > 0) {

        File some_file = new File("./some");
        File other_file = new File("./other");

        // Do things to these two files, like read them
        // or parse as JSON or whatever.
    }
    super.setup(context);
}
```

Comment: And where is this documented?

Answer (score 5):

The new DistributedCache API for YARN/MR2 is found in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` class.

```
   Job.addCacheFile()
```

Unfortunately, there aren't as of yet many comprehensive tutorial-style examples of this.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#addCacheFile%28java.net.URI%29

Comment: I have no idea how to retrieve these cache files added using `Job.addCacheFile(URI)`. It does not work for me using the old way (`context.getCacheFiles()`), because the files are null.

Answer (score 2):

I did not use job.addCacheFile(). Instead I used -files option like "-files /path/to/myfile.txt#myfile" as before. Then in the mapper or reducer code I use the method below:

```
/**
 * This method can be used with local execution or HDFS execution. 
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param symLink
 * @param throwExceptionIfNotFound
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static File findDistributedFileBySymlink(JobContext context, String symLink, boolean throwExceptionIfNotFound) throws IOException
{
    URI[] uris = context.getCacheFiles();
    if(uris==null||uris.length==0)
    {
        if(throwExceptionIfNotFound)
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find file with symlink '"+symLink+"' in distributed cache");
        return null;
    }
    URI symlinkUri = null;
    for(URI uri: uris)
    {
        if(symLink.equals(uri.getFragment()))
        {
            symlinkUri = uri;
            break;
        }
    }   
    if(symlinkUri==null)
    {
        if(throwExceptionIfNotFound)
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find file with symlink '"+symLink+"' in distributed cache");
        return null;
    }
    //if we run this locally the file system URI scheme will be "file" otherwise it should be a symlink
    return "file".equalsIgnoreCase(FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration()).getScheme())?(new File(symlinkUri.getPath())):new File(symLink);

}
```

Then in mapper/reducer:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    super.setup(context);

    File file = HadoopUtils.findDistributedFileBySymlink(context,"myfile",true);
    ... do work ...
}
```

Note that if I used "-files /path/to/myfile.txt" directly then I need to use "myfile.txt" to access the file since that is the default symlink name.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And not only is DistributedCach deprecated but getLocalCacheFiles and "new Job" too. So what worked for me is the following:

Driver:

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
...
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());
```

In Mapper/Reducer setup:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    super.setup(context);

    URI[] files = context.getCacheFiles(); // getCacheFiles returns null

    Path file1path = new Path(files[0])
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solution mentioned worked for me in completeness . It could because Hadoop version keeps changing I am using hadoop 2.6.4. Essentially, DistributedCache is deprecated so I didnt want to use that. As some of the post suggest us to use addCacheFile() however, it has changed a bit. Here is how it worked for me

```
job.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://X.X.X.X:9000/EnglishStop.txt#EnglishStop.txt"));
```

Here X.X.X.X can be Master IP address or localhost. The EnglishStop.txt was stored in HDFS at / location.

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

The output is

```
-rw-r--r--   3 centos supergroup       1833 2016-03-12 20:24 /EnglishStop.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - centos supergroup          0 2016-03-12 19:46 /test
```

Funny but convenient, #EnglishStop.txt means now we can access it as "EnglishStop.txt" in mapper. Here is the code for the same

```
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException     
{
    File stopwordFile = new File("EnglishStop.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(stopwordFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    while ((stopWord = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // stopWord is a word read from Cache
    }
}
```

This just worked for me. You can read line from the file stored in HDFS

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something else to patapouf_ai's answer. If you need to read the content of the file in the setup after saving the file in the cache, you have to do something like this:

In Mapper/Reducer setup:

```
protected void setup (Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);           
        //Get FileSystem object to read file
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        URI[] files = context.getCacheFiles();
        Path patternsFile = new Path(files[0]);
        parseSkipFile(patternsFile,fs);
}
        
private void parseSkipFile(Path patternsFile, FileSystem fs) {
        try {
            BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(patternsFile)));
            String pattern = null;
            while ((pattern = fis.readLine()) != null) {
                //Here you can do whatever you want by reading the file line by line
                patternsToSkip.add(pattern);
            }
            fis.close();
            
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '" + patternsFile + "' : " + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe)); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been tested for `hadoop 3.3.2`.

Add this in the driver class (we need mainly `addCacheFile`)

```
package src;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "distributed cache");
        job.addCacheFile(new Path("/fileToBeCachedFromHDFS.txt").toUri());
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }
}
```

Then,access the cached file inside `setup` function (using `FileSystem` and `BufferedReader`).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;

public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        URI[] cacheFile = context.getCacheFiles(); 

        if (cacheFile!=null && cacheFile.length > 0) {
                // 
                try{
                    //
                    String line = ""; 
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
                    Path getFilePath = new Path(cacheFile[0].toString());
                    
                    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(fs.open(getFilePath)));
                                        
                    while((line = myReader.readLine())!= null) {
                        String[] words = line.split(",");
                    }

                    myReader.close();
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("An error occured");
                }
            }
    }
}
```