# How to set the path of library file created using JNI in hadoop map reduce

Tags: java, c, hadoop, java-native-interface

I am using a native method in my mapper code.

```
class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{
   static{
      System.loadLibrary("myjni");
   }
   public native String getRow(String record, String query);

   public void map(...){
      //...
   }
}
```

I performed all necessary steps to create JNI library file - `.so`. And I also copied this `.so` file to hdfs. But still hadoop is not recognizing the path. Its giving an error - `no myjni in java.libarary.path.`

How to let know mapper the path of native library file.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Files in HDFS are essentially unknown to everything except software explicitly designed to be HDFS-aware.  In particular, Java and its class loaders know nothing of HDFS.  To make HDFS-based files appear in the native file system for such uses, use the "DistrubutedCache" API in your MapReduce job.  This is a mechanism for caching HDFS-based files and archives to your local file system (in YARN, a similar feature is called "resource localization").  See the following for help:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239722/hadoop-distributedcache-is-deprecated-what-is-the-preferred-api)
[yahoo tutorial](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html)