# passing URI as a runtime variable to distributed cache in mapreduce hadoop

Tags: caching, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I am using distributed cache in my mapreduce program and I am passing three variables to this mapreduce program `input file`, `output dir` and `config file`.

I want to add the third argument i.e config file to the Distributed Cache.

I am setting the parameter as follows in `run()` method of the MapReduce Driver:-

```
conf.set("CONF_XML", args[2]);
```

How to add this file into distributed cache in the same method. how do I do that ?

Usually we add using `URI(new (file path));`

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(file_path), conf); << here how to pass the argument parameter?
```

Comment: Use of `DistributedCache.addCacheFile` is deprecated take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239722/hadoop-distributedcache-is-deprecated-what-is-the-preferred-api) for usage on the new API `job.addCacheFile()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the file path argument to the DistributedCache API as URI

DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(args[2])**.toUri()**,job.getConfiguration());