# Maintain a data structure in master node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've written a MR algorithm on some data to create a data structure. After creation I need to answer some queries. To answer these queries faster I created a metadata (around several MBs) from the result.

Now my question is this:

Is it possible to create this metadata in the memory of Master Node to avoid file I/O as a result answer queries faster?

Comment: What do you mean by create a data structure? When you say queries, do you mean you're going to run a MR job for the query? Please explain the scenario.

Comment: Imagine like this, you have B-Tree in the memory to point to data files on HDFS. For queries you refer to B-Tree to access some data files and then run a MR job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, based on the OP response to the other answer, the metadata will be required for another MR job. Using Distributed cache in this case is rather easy:

In the driver class:

```
public class DriverClass extends Configured{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    /* ...some init code... */


    /*
    * Instantiate a Job object for your job's configuration.  
    */
    Configuration job_conf = new Configuration();
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("path/to/your/data.txt").toUri(),job_conf);
    Job job = new Job(job_conf);

    /* ... configure and start the job... */

  }
}
```

In the mapper class you can read the data at the setup stage and make it available for the map class:

```
public class YourMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

  private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Override
  protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException {

    /* Get the cached archives/files */
    Path[] cached_file = new Path[0];
    try {
      cached_file = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      // TODO add error code
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    File f = new File (cached_file[0].toString());
    try {
      /* Read the data some thing like: */
      lines = Files.readLines(f,charset);
    } catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      /*
      * In the mapper - use the data as needed
      */

  }
}
```

Note that Distributed Cache can hold more the plain text file. You can use archives (zip, tar..) and even a full java class (jar files).

Also note that in newer Hadoop implementations, the Distributed Cache API is found in the Job class itself. Refer to [this API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239722/hadoop-distributedcache-is-deprecated-what-is-the-preferred-api).