# MapReduce: How to pass HashMap to mappers

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming

I'm designing the new generation of an analysis system which needs to process many events from many sensors in near-real time. And to do that I want to use one of the Big Data Analytics platforms such as `Hadoop`, `Spark Streaming` or `Flink`.

In order to analyze each event I need to use some meta-data from a table (DB) or at-least load it into a cached map.

The problem is that each mapper is going to be parallelized on several nodes.

So I have two things to handle:

- First, how to load/pass a HashMap to a mapper?
- Is there any way to keep the HashMap Consistent between the mappers?

Comment: DistributedCache is what you're looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239722/hadoop-distributedcache-is-deprecated-what-is-the-preferred-api. You can make metadata files available to all Mappers.

Comment: You could also build the hashmap in the `setup()` method of each mapper by querying your DB perhaps.

Comment: Will you be using Hadoop or Spark ? The solution can be quite different.
Also, do you need every mapper to have the same info or is it specific to each mapper ?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize HashMap structure to file, store it in HDFS and at the MapReduce job configuration phase use [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#DistributedCache) to spread file with serialized HashMap across all the mappers. Then at map phase each mapper can read the file, de-serialize and then access this HashMap.